# LXDE is not starting after upgrading to 3.5.0-26-generic kernel

Tags: upgrade, kernel, lxde

I've upgraded my Lubuntu distribution to the 3.5.0-26-generic kernel and after rebooting, LXDE is not starting up anymore. I had to revert to 3.5.0-25-generic, which still works. Any suggestions on how can I fix the problem?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you do anything special to upgrade the kernel or was it just by way of regular updates? I'm asking because I'm using Lubuntu 12.10 and have "3.5.0-26-generic" which hasn't caused a problem. What exactly happens for you?

Answer (score 0):

If you have an SSD this might help:
In /etc/init/lightdm.conf add just above "exec lightdm":
sleep 2

If you find file ~/.Xauthority owned by root then do this:
rm -f ~/.Xauthority
sudo service lightdm restart